# Meaning of "Arrays.sort(intervals,(arr1,arr2) -> Integer.compare(arr1[0],arr2[0]))"

Tags: java

What does this mean? I am having trouble finding about this

```java
Arrays.sort(intervals,(arr1,arr2) -> Integer.compare(arr1[0],arr2[0]));
```

Comment: [Sorting array of arrays with custom comparator?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-)

Comment: Hi, kindly show what you've previously researched about the topic, and what is the part that's troubling you :) marking the post as more detail needed.

Answer (score 2):

The first input (`intervals`) is your array which will be sorted, and the second (`(arr1,arr2) -> Interger.compare(arr1[0],arr2[0])`) is the comparator which is passed in a [lambda expression](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_lambda.asp) format.

Your comparator is using the natural comparing between integers. Your final result will be an ascending sorted array in the variable `intervals`

Take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)) link to java doc.